# Youtube Analytics APi Error while trying to generate the report for traffic source

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

When I specify the following metrics and dimensions the query does not work:

Metrics - views
Dimensions - insightTrafficSourceType
When I specify the following metrics and dimensions the query does not work:

Metrics - views
Dimensions - insightTrafficSourceType

Query URL -https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?endDate=2017-01-30&startDate=2017-01-28&metrics=views&ids=contentOwner==CONTENT_OWNER_ID&dimensions=insightTrafficSourceType

Error :message The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v2/available_reports for a list of supported queries.

Answer (score 0):

When you are requesting a content owner report for traffic sources, you must also provide a filter to the query.

The filter can be one of the following:
video, channel, group, or a supported combination of uploaderType and claimedStatus

See documentation for the content owner traffic sources report:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/content_owner_reports#traffic-source-reports